# I cannot figure out why i am getting an indention error for my functions

Tags: python-3.x, function, indentation

I am getting the following error when running my function in python 3.

IndentationError: expected an indented block after function definition on line 1

Here is my very simple function

```
def Calculate_total(a,b):   #Parameters: a and b
    total = a + b           #Task Addition
    return total            #Output Sum of a and b\
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to properly format your code. We can't tell from that mess whether you have an indentation issue or not.

Comment: That sounds like you’re somehow running the first line of code by itself, without the rest of the function definition.  You haven’t told us what IDE or other environment you’re using to run this code, so we can’t tell you how to run it correctly.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who responded. It turns out I was just running the first line of code and not the subsequent lines. I believe my issue was using the REPL terminal and attempting to highlight a single line of code in my function with the assumption that the remaining code block would run. This was not the case and instead i needed to highlight the entire block and then run the function.

Answer (score 1):

There must be another problem, as suggested in the comments. I tried to run your code with no problem. Please see my code block and try that one.

```
def Calculate_total(a,b):   #Parameters: a and b
    total = a + b           #Task Addition
    return total            #Output Sum of a and b\

def main():
    print(Calculate_total(1,2))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I believe my issue was using the REPL terminal and attempting to highlight a single line of code in my function with the assumption that the remaining code block would run. This was not the case and instead i needed to highlight the entire block and then run the function. Your comment helped me realize this, thank you.

Comment: No problem, good that you found the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to everyone who responded. It turns out I was just running the first line of code and not the subsequent lines. I believe my issue was using the REPL terminal in VS Code and attempting to highlight a single line of code in my function with the assumption that the remaining code block would run. This was not the case and instead i needed to highlight the entire block and then run the function.

Answer (score -1):

Python relies on proper indentation to define blocks of code. Make sure that the code inside your function is indented correctly. Here's a corrected version of your code:

```
def Calculate_total(a, b):   # Parameters: a and b
    total = a + b            # Task: Addition
    return total             # Output: Sum of a and b
```

Comment: This is not a corrected version rather an exact **Copy** of the code posted by the OP which doesn't seem to have any indentation problem.